# Unparseable Date exception at offset(0) for date parsing from String Android

Tags: java, android, date

I am trying to parse my String which is in this format `19, 1 19, 2016 12:25 pm` and my SimpleDateFormat is `EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a`. I parse my above String to date as `Tuesday, January 19, 2016 12:25 pm`, but it is throwing parceable exception here. My code is given below, please help me out here.

```
stestRequest = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"); 
// stringDate = "19, 1 19, 2016 12:25 pm"
dateRequestSelected       = stestRequest.parse(stringDate);
```

Please help me out here, thanks in advance.

Comment: you stringdate has a different format then in your pattern. What should be the first 19?

Comment: **stringDate** must is ``Date`` format

Comment: @DanhDC NO parse expact a string.

Comment: @Jens thanks for your comment here. 19 is my Day of the month. I need to display it as Tuesday.

Comment: So you have to parse it and then use format() to format your date.

Comment: @Jens but i need a date object as well. Thats why i was trying to parse my String in Date object. Please suggest me a way here that i need to make a Date Object with my String, in simple words i need to convert my this string in Date object like Tuesday, January 19, 2016 12:25 pm

Comment: @Android_Zapier but why yu have the 19 two times in your string?

Comment: In first time i need to show it like Wednesay and in second part i need to show it like 19(Like Day in Number). Thats why i used 19 two times. Please suggest and correct me in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"); //your date string format is : 1 19, 2016 12:25 pm
Date stringDate = simpledateformat.parse(date, pos);
SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"); //Tuesday, January 19, 2016 12:25 pm,
System.out.println(dayFormat.format(stringDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

So if your date as String is `1 19, 2016 12:25 pm`

You ned to define a Date Format wich correspondens to your string:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd',' yyyy hh:mm aa");
```

Then you have to parse the string:

```
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

Next Step is to define a Format for the Output:

```
SimpleDateFormat stestRequest = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE',' MMMM dd',' yyyy hh:mm a");
```

And then you have to cal Format:

```
  stestRequest.format(date);
```

For more information see the documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
        String stringDate = "01 19, 2016 12:25 pm";
        SimpleDateFormat oldSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
        SimpleDateFormat newSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
        String dateRequestSelected = null;
        try {
            dateRequestSelected = newSdf.format(oldSdf.parse(stringDate));
            Log.e("Date", dateRequestSelected);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Output:** Tuesday, January 19, 2016 12:25 PM

**Edited:**

```
        String stringDate = "01 19, 2016 12:25 pm";
        SimpleDateFormat oldSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
        SimpleDateFormat newSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
        Date dateRequestSelected = null;
        try {
            dateRequestSelected = newSdf.parse(newSdf.format(oldSdf.parse(stringDate)));
            Log.e("Date", dateRequestSelected+"");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Output:** Tue Jan 19 12:25:00 GMT+05:30 2016

Comment: thanks for your answer here. Can you please tell ,e one thing, is it possible to make Date Object Like Tuesday, January 19, 2016 12:25 PM. As i have to send Date object like this on server.

Comment: Yes, you can but it will change output. Check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The new Date().toString() method will give you a date formatted how you want. You can write that to a file, then when you're reading it, you can parse a date using new Date(string). For example:

```
package Testers;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class Datestufff {

public void recordCurrentDate(File file){
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        String date = new Date().toString();
        writer.write(date);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getDate(File file){   
    String date = "Unknown!";
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        date = line;
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}

public void recordDate(File file, Date date){
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.write(date.toString());
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}